# Linq Select method with a method as a parameter with two parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I'm developing a library with .NET Framework 4.5.1 with C#.

I have this code:

```
user.Groups = modelUser.Groups
    .Select(CreateGroup)
    .ToList();
```

`CreateGroup` prototype is:

```
 public Models.Group CreateGroup(Data.Models.Group modelGroup, bool createMembers)
```

It has two parameters.

How do I have to modify `Select` to pass the second parameter, `createMembers`, to `CreateGroup`?

Comment: What you want to pass for `createMembers` parameter? true or false or a variable ?

Comment: A bool variable or true or false.

Comment: simply do that explicitly, don't use method group conversion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using method group conversion to pass the method `CreateGroup` as a parameter.

If you use a lambda you can easily use the parameters you want, e.g.

```
user.Groups = modelUsers.Groups
                        .Select(g => CreateGroup(g, true))
                        .ToList();
```